# Ubuntu Run C++ executable from Matlab--permission

Tags: c++, matlab, shell, ubuntu, executable

I have a C++ executable file and I could run it using terminal command line normally. Now I want to run exactly the same command in matlab using 'system' or 'unix' function. But I have to add 'sudo' in the same command and type in the password. Could someone help solve such permission problem?

Here is example:

The command line I need to run is :
./DenseTrackStab test.avi |gzip> ./output/DenseTrackStab.txt.gz
which is to extract some features of the video and save it to some path.
So in matlab I wrote:

system( ['./DenseTrackStab ' video_path ' |gzip> ' IDT_savepath  /DenseTrackStab.txt.gz']);

where video_path='test.avi' , IDT_savepath='./output' and DenseTrackStab is the C++ executable file.

But it could not be run in matlab, currently I have to use

system( ['sudo ./DenseTrackStab ' video_path ' |gzip> ' IDT_savepath '/DenseTrackStab.txt.gz']);

Comment: Can you give further details?

Comment: Why do you have to use `sudo`?

Comment: I added the example. If I do not add the 'sudo', it seems the DenseTrackStab could not read in the video so the ouput feature is empty.

Comment: What does `ls -lah output` show? Why can't it be run?

Comment: the 'output ' is the new created directory to save the output feature, so it will shows drwxrwxr-x 2 tyzhang tyz 4.0K Oct 25 19:43 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 tyz tyz 4.0K Oct 25 19:43 ..